# Find the expression of $\arctan \dfrac{2}{x}$ by the combination of $\log(|x+\alpha|),\ \ \log(|x^2+\beta x+\gamma|),\ \ \arctan(\mu x+\nu), C$

Tags: integration, analysis, solution-verification

There should exist a linear combination of the functions $$\log(|x+\alpha|),\ \ \log(|x^2+\beta x+\gamma|),\ \ \arctan(\mu x+\nu).$$ to express the function $\arctan \frac{2}{x}$

The way I deal with it is by taking the derivative of $\arctan \frac{2}{x}$ first then I get $$ \dfrac{-2}{x^2+4} $$
Then I think after I integrate this rational function, I can get the answer. The integration result is $$ -\arctan \dfrac{x}{2} + \dfrac{\pi}{2} $$
However, I use Desmos to draw the picture of the result, I found that the result is the same as $\arctan \dfrac{2}{x} $ when $x\geq 0$ but they are different when $ x<0$
[image]

Thus I wonder that is my result right or wrong? Thanks!

Comment: $\arctan \frac 2x$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: The black and red curves have the same derivative at all $x$ other than $0$, but on the two sides of the discontinuity, the constant of integration can be different. So the two curves have two constant differences for $x<0$ and $x>0$.

Comment: What was it that made you decide to use $+\frac \pi 2$ for your constant of integration ?

Comment: @peterwhy So you mean that my answer is partially right since the answer should be a piecewise function?

Comment: If defined piecewise,

$$\arctan \frac 2x = -\arctan\frac x2 + \begin{cases}C_1& x< 0\\
C_2 & x> 0\end{cases}$$

You chose a $C_2$ that works for $x>0$, but should have chosen a different $C_1$ for $x<0$.